# How to get the norm of the vector corresponding to a particular row in a SciPy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a sparse matrix random matrix created as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import rand
foo = rand(100, 100, density=0.1, format='csr')
```

I would like to get the norm of the vector corresponding to a particular row:

```
row = foo.getrow(bar)
print(np.linalg.norm(row))
```

But this code produces an error:

```
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to extract the non-zero data and then compute its L2 norm -

```
out = np.linalg.norm(row.data)
```